# Safe to replace $HTTP_XXXX_VARS with $_XXXX

Tags: php, http

Was wondering if it is safe to mass replace the `$HTTP_` variables with the `$_XXX` replacements?

```
$HTTP_POST_VARS
$HTTP_GET_VARS
$HTTP_COOKIE_VARS
$HTTP_SESSION_VARS
$HTTP_SERVER_VARS
```

Comment: I wouldn't mess with PHP's global variables.  Why would you want to?  You could do `$_POST = $HTTP_POST_VARS;` which will leave the global variable intact.

Comment: I think he means to do this replacement across all his source files.

Comment: @Barmar there can be a config file, which is ALWAYS included.

Comment: @Jari How is that relevant to the question. PHP already sets these variables to the same thing, his question is about updating all his source code that uses the old variables, and whether it's safe to do a mass edit to use the new variables.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, gentlemen...

Comment: I couldnt find any advice online about mass replacing them in your code, so even though it all seems to be working and indeed would not work with the older variables, I still am curious was it an SOP thing to do since the $HTTP's are deprecated.  Otherwise, what else do you do?

Comment: Allow me to backup a little,  I have some ancient code (2003 highly modified oscommerce) full of the $HTTP variables, and my website ignored them.  Dont know why, and my host doesnt either.  And it is curious that another website on the same server handles the old vars just fine. I mass replaced the old vars and everything seems to work well, but was wondering if it would come back to haunt me. Was there something else I should have done or do, to fix the old vars?

Comment: @Barmar well, kay, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is safe.

In each of the documentations for [`$_POST`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php), [`$_GET`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), and [so on](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php), there is a single line which states (substituting `X` for whichever entry):

> `$HTTP_X_VARS` contains the same initial information, but is not a [superglobal](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php). (Note that `$HTTP_X_VARS` and `$_X` are different variables and that PHP handles them as such)

So, they are different variables (modifying one does not modify the other), but they contain the same information if unmodified by you.

As a note, since your question was a tad ambiguous: *You should not modify these variables*.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the superglobals? They're not depreciated.

```
$_POST
$_GET
$_COOKIE
$_SESSION
$_SERvER
```

They've been around since PHP 4 so it's safe to replace them unless you're on some ancient server still running PHP 3.x

Comment: That's what he's asking about. Can he do a global replacement in his source code, replacing all `$HTTP_POST_VARS` with `$_POST`.